# After setting the same width via python font forge cannot edit font anymore

Tags: fonts, fontforge

Can you please help me?
Recently I bought monospaced font and a little bit modified it for myself.
After that something with width in that font was broken, so I run python on it:

```
font=fontforge.open("font.ttf")
    for i in font.selection.all():
        try:
            font[i].width=1800
        except Exception as ex:
          pass
font.save("new_font.ttf")
```

After that seems like there are so many nodes created for curved lines etc.

Currently, I can open it FontForge.

It works normally in IDE etc..
But from now I cannot change glyph in FontForge - when I try to open Element-Style-ChangeGLyph it hangs for a long time even for one element.

Why is this happens? How can I fix it?
Also the question, does many nodes makes font 'heavy' to render for IDE etc?

Thank you in advance.